# How do I highlight all columns matching a number with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following code:

```
var toHighlight = $('th').filter(function(){return $(this).text() == max})

var col = $(toHighlight).index();
$("td, th").filter(":nth-child(" + (col + 1) + ")").css("background-color", "gold")
```

The purpose of it is to find the column with the highest number and change the background-color. It does this well. My problem is, if there are multiple columns that contain the highest number I'd like it to change the color of all of them. Right now, it only does the first one it finds.

How can I change this to change the background-color for all columns matching max?

Comment: And your other code, an example of HTML?

Comment: `toHighlight` contains a selection of `<th>` elements. Just iterate over them.

Comment: Is max a variable (in this case, what is setting it?), or a text (in this case, you forgot the quotes around it) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must want to use `each()` to iterate through your filtered `tr`s.
Then, you can easily highlight all the elements using your code.
(You were quite close)

Here is a working snippet:

```js
// I've done like max was a text.
var toHighlight = $('th').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'max'
});
$(toHighlight).each(function() {
  var col = $(this).index();
  $("td, th").filter(":nth-child(" + (col + 1) + ")").css("background-color", "gold");
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>x</th>
      <th>max</th>
      <th>x</th>
      <th>max</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: How does this solve the question/problem? It does the exact same thing but with a fixed column.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't understand the question well. Was waiting for comments from the OP. But I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

@Mamun is right that you need to iterate over the toHighlight.  To get the full column highlighted you just need to get the index for each column and then set all of the "td, th" in that column.

Given this HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>7</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>7</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>d</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It would use this JS:

```
var max='7';
var toHighlight = $('th').filter(function(){return $(this).text() == max});

$(toHighlight).each(function(a, colItem){
   var col = $(colItem).index();
   $("td, th").filter(":nth-child(" + (col + 1) + ")").css("background-color", "gold");
});
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yd4c013j/